# Create barcode ean13 with format like 00000012345

Tags: python, barcode, generated, ean-13

I was try to create barcode using python. I was try to use pyBarcode library. When i was try to create barcode from value 12345. I got result like 123452 or 123454. But the format what i need it like 13 digit and like 0000001234567 or 1123456000008.

I was try like this :

```
import barcode

ean = barcode.get_barcode_class("ean13")
ean_final = ean(u"12345")
```

Comment: EAN-13 takes 12 digits plus 1 check digit, you may fill '0' into your value and the library will calculate the check digit.

Comment: If add '0' like you said,That's like static, right ? i need it as dynamic. There is any library can generate it as automaticaly that i can use ?

Comment: Use [str.ljust(width[, fillchar])](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust)